# How to trace Javascript events (Stack Trace )?

Tags: javascript, stack-trace

In any programming language, I can trace any function and know which function is called by other. But in Javascript , I don't know how, since **the code is not written by me** and Firebug  does not give this feature - as far as I know.

**An example :**

I want to display the function names of each function that is called when clicking on XYZ Element, and display them in order.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found this: [**A javascript stacktrace in any browser**](http://eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/), [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20774/james-mcmahon) says they have a [github account now](https://github.com/eriwen/javascript-stacktrace)

```
function printStackTrace() {
  var callstack = [];
  var isCallstackPopulated = false;
  try {
    i.dont.exist+=0; //doesn't exist- that's the point
  } catch(e) {
    if (e.stack) { //Firefox
      var lines = e.stack.split('\n');
      for (var i=0, len=lines.length; i<len; i++) {
        if (lines[i].match(/^\s*[A-Za-z0-9\-_\$]+\(/)) {
          callstack.push(lines[i]);
        }
      }
      //Remove call to printStackTrace()
      callstack.shift();
      isCallstackPopulated = true;
    }
    else if (window.opera && e.message) { //Opera
      var lines = e.message.split('\n');
      for (var i=0, len=lines.length; i<len; i++) {
        if (lines[i].match(/^\s*[A-Za-z0-9\-_\$]+\(/)) {
          var entry = lines[i];
          //Append next line also since it has the file info
          if (lines[i+1]) {
            entry += " at " + lines[i+1];
            i++;
          }
          callstack.push(entry);
        }
      }
      //Remove call to printStackTrace()
      callstack.shift();
      isCallstackPopulated = true;
    }
  }
  if (!isCallstackPopulated) { //IE and Safari
    var currentFunction = arguments.callee.caller;
    while (currentFunction) {
      var fn = currentFunction.toString();
      var fname = fn.substring(fn.indexOf("function") + 8, fn.indexOf('')) || 'anonymous';
      callstack.push(fname);
      currentFunction = currentFunction.caller;
    }
  }
  output(callstack);
}

function output(arr) {
  // Output however you want
  alert(arr.join('\n\n'));
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that they have a github site now, https://github.com/eriwen/javascript-stacktrace

Answer (score 3):

You can see the stack trace of any error with the `stack()` function call (on Firefox).  Creating a simple function to print a stack trace could look like this:

```
function getStackTrace() {
  try {
    unusedVariable++; // This creates an error we can trace
  }
  catch (e) {
    return e.stack;
  }
}
```

Other browsers have different ways of printing the stack trace, but this should get you what you need for Firefox.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That should be e.stack at least on Firefox 3.6.6

Answer (score 0):

[DynaTrace AJAX](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/pages/) has some of the features like that. Not exactly what you are looking for but gives you the events and functions bound on an element and helps your troubleshooting. Had a free download, check it.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to debug your code, your best option is to get a debugger plug-in for your browser. The Firebug plug-in does provide stack traces. ([see here](http://getfirebug.com/logging))

If you want to do it from within your code, there is no standard language feature of JavaScript that allows you to do this. Different browsers *may* implement non-standard extensions, but you shouldn't rely on them.

Answer (score 0):

As "Casablanca" mentions... please note from the site of the aforementioned js-stack-trace (
http://www.eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/ ) that in FireFox and Chrome:

> **Obvious easy way: Firebug, Chrome Dev Tools, Dragonfly etc.**
>
> You can easily get a stack trace at any time by calling
>   console.trace() in your Javascript or in the Firebug console.

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like you want to inspect the stack and take pieces of the information (the function names), sounds like you need

- [stackinfo](https://github.com/fresheneesz/stackinfo)

which was built exactly for that purpose.