# Automatic load section, but close if another

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my "overview" section to be displayed when the website is loading, but hidden when one of the other sections are loaded. How can I do that?

```html
<section id="overview" style="display: none;">
    Test
    <p>Example</p>
</section>
```

I already tried to work with JavaScript, but my code there was garbage and helped nothing.

Comment: "Loaded" how?  There is no guarantee the page will be displayed before the entire source is loaded.  If you want a "splash" screen, then put that in your main HTML, and run Javascript  that removes it.

Comment: I have a header with different links to sections. But when nothing is selected, everything is white. I want, that when I didn't selected something text is shown. But if a section is shown, the text should be hided

Comment: You can use window.onload event listener together with setTimeout() function to display none this section after some delay. This will be a good option unless other section show after another event (not loaded with dom content)

Comment: So you pick one of the sections to NOT have `display: none`, so it gets displayed initially, then change the settings after.

Comment: Wdym @Tim Roberts? How can I do that in my js? I already tried with checking if it was clicked in the header or sth like that, but that was not good

Comment: [Similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9550760/2518285) have been asked before

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide page until everything is loaded Advanced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550760/hide-page-until-everything-is-loaded-advanced)

Comment: I already solved it, but I can’t check the solution I postet below. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

My solution is following:

I have my overview div in the HTML file:

```html
<div id="overview">
    Test
    <p>Example</p>
</div>
```

Which is on load automatically via JavaScript shown:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('overview').style.display = 'block';
};
```

Now I have a function that hides an element from the site via JavaScript:

```js
function hideSection(sectionId) {
    document.getElementById(sectionId).style.display = 'none';
}
```

All what I do now is, to call that function when I click something in the nav bar:

```html
<header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#example1" onclick="hideSection('overview')">Example 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#example2" onclick="hideSection('overview')">Example 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#example3" onclick="hideSection('overview')">Example 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Now it automatically loads the overview div when the site is loaded, but when I choose something in the navigation bar it hide this div and shows the sections.