# JS: Detect if script is being runned from console

Tags: javascript

How would I go about if I wanted to make a javascript code that will detect any script being runned by the web console?

I know that if I write this code:

```
if (window.console && window.console.chrome) {
//is open
};
```

I will be able to see if the console is running. But I want to detect if any code is being runned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if any JavaScript function is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790099/detect-if-any-javascript-function-is-running)

Comment: No, you can never detect what the user is doing with your page on his computer.

Comment: what kind of script are you considering here? a script that access your javascript funcions or a script that does some variable assignment ? eg: global.func(), where global is present in your code  or var x =1 ;